# Authentication issues when trying to register new app in Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I want to access the outlook API with a Python application. I followed [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/python?context=outlook%2Fcontext&tabs=aad&tutorial-step=1) but quickly ran into authentication issues. Tried it with my existing private Microsoft account and with a new created account, but ran into authentication issues quickly. Whenever I try to do anything in the portal, I get this message:
[image]

Already checked in with the general Microsoft support. They directed me towards Azure support, but I can't reach anybody there.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]

The error usually occurs if the Microsoft personal account is not added as an external/guest user to an Azure AD tenant.

**To resolve the error**, contact the Global admin to invite the account as a guest user like below:

[image]

Once the admin invites, you will get an email notification to accept the invitation like below:

[image]

After accepting the invite, **the Personal Microsoft account will be added to the tenant** successfully like below:

[image]

And now you will be able to access the Azure Portal without any issue and you can also create your own tenant to have admin access.

***If still the issue persists***, try the below:

- Sign out from the active session and sign in incognito window or any different browser.
- Clear browser cache and cookies and try.
- Confirm whether the admin has set any External user settings that is restricting the access:

[image]

**Reference:**

[Error AADSTS50020 - User account from identity provider does not exist in tenant - Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/error-code-aadsts50020-user-account-identity-provider-does-not-exist#cause-3-signed-in-to-the-wrong-tenant)

Comment: Sounds good. Unfortunately, I cannot even access the user section or any other part in the portal. It says "No Access" with error code 403

Comment: Yeah to do the above settings, you have to contact your Tenant Administrator.

Comment: Ok, could you please tell me how I can do that? Is there a specific contact form or mail address? Thanks

Comment: Tenant Administrator is one who has Global Admin Role in the Tenant you are trying to login.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what to do and can't validate your answer. Can't even create a support ticket. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Could you please confirm what kind of subscription you are using?

Answer (score 0):

When looking into the [Build Python apps with Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/python?context=outlook%2Fcontext&tabs=aad) tutorial that you followed, one of the pre-requisites mentioned [signing up for the Microsoft 365 Developer Program](https://developer.microsoft.com/microsoft-365/dev-program) to get a free Microsoft 365 subscription. After you sign-up, you'll need to use the Microsoft 365 developer sandbox credentials in order to continue following the tutorial without having to leverage your own [Azure AD tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-create-new-tenant) or subscription ([pay-as-you-go](https://signup.azure.com/signup?offer=ms-azr-0003p&appId=102&redirectURL=https%3A%2F%2Fazure.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fpay-as-you-go%2Fwelcome%2F&l=en-us&correlationId=709ae7cb43144c5e937328311f11e208)).

**[Build Python apps with Microsoft Graph:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/python?context=outlook%2Fcontext&tabs=aad)**

1. [Join the Microsoft 365 Developer Program](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/dev-program)
2. Deploy the Developer Sandbox
3. Using the Microsoft 365 Developer subscription(s) info you'll be able to login to the Azure Portal or Azure Active Directory admin center.

`Note: You can navigate to your developer tenant using - https://aad.portal.azure.com/<<SandboxTenantName>>.onmicrosoft.com`, or when prompted to sign in use your sandboxes' admin account.

[image: Microsoft 365 Developer Sandbox login]

If you only signed up for a new [personal Microsoft account](https://signup.live.com/signup?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=12&ct=1454618383&rver=6.4.6456.0&wp=MBI_SSL_SHARED&wreply=https://mail.live.com/default.aspx&id=64855&cbcxt=mai&bk=1454618383&uiflavor=web&uaid=b213a65b4fdc484382b6622b3ecaa547&mkt=E-US&lc=1033&lic=1) (Outlook), you'll notice that once you sign into the Azure AD Admin Center, your `Outlook.com` user isn't associated with any Azure tenants, and you'll run into the authentication issue error message that you referenced, so you'll have to [create your own Azure AD tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-create-new-tenant) by signing up for an [Azure Free Trial](https://azure.microsoft.com/free/?WT.mc_id=A261C142F) or [Pay-as-you-go](https://signup.azure.com/signup?offer=ms-azr-0003p&appId=102&redirectURL=https%3A%2F%2Fazure.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fpay-as-you-go%2Fwelcome%2F&l=en-us&correlationId=709ae7cb43144c5e937328311f11e208).

[image: Outlook Login]

I hope this helps!